# Communication between stacked Scenes - Fish-Net : Networking

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, server, client

A friend and I are trying to create a game for a school project that requires scene stacking. Each player has its own scene (that is stacked). The issue that we encounter is how to communicate between the stacked scenes (if that’s even possible).

What we want is that when a player in his scene presses a certain key, a variable inside a script of an object present on every other stacked scene gets incremented.

Player 1 presses a key -> All other players (clients) receive a incrementation in their scene.

We are trying to work with RPC and/or SyncVar, but having a lot of struggle on how to do it.

Any Ideas ?

Thank you :)

We tried using ServerRpc and then ObserverRpc and SyncVar

Comment: You don’t need any form of networking. Static variables work fine, you can have DontDestroyOnLoad objects which exist outside of any scene, and many other methods.

Comment: Scene stacking? Is that having multiple scenes open at the same time? (additive scenes)